# VS Code snippet get Solution name

Tags: c#, code-snippets

Im trying to create a snippet which add comments to the code and extract the current data. I am using VS 2017, but can access other versions

Im following: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx on how to create snippets (C#)

Idea is to create a surrounds with code snippet to put a comment before and after the selection (which works)

```
<Snippet>
  <Code Language="CSharp">
    <![CDATA[// Start - ABC001_FixRounding/MyName/11/01/2017
    $selected$
    // End - ABC001_FixRounding/MyName/<TodaysDate>  
    $end
    ]]>
  </Code>
</Snippet>
```

Idea being that the comment will be like // //

Is that a possibility using snippets or am i heading the wrong way ?

Comment: The right way to track when changed what when is in your version control system (VCS). Many will even provide a tool to track the most recent change on a line by line basis (eg. Annotate in TFSVS, blame in git). Adding comments to do this just makes the code harder to follow and maintain. If you are not using a VCS then that's your most critical problem.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I am aware of this. However, i do end up doing some code merges from 3rd parties and I want to have a visual traction of what is mine vs others without having to rely on VSTS (Which is what i use). 
Should I be looking at an Add-in, and what kind of Addin which can add changes to the Code ?